# what does "at best minimally successful" mean

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

I think it means "just barely meeting the targets and that's it! nothing more than that", or does it mean that somebody did such a great job that successful is too small to describe it? I'm a bit confused.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If an effort is "at best minimally successful," it is very slightly successful if viewed as optimistically as possible. It could be not successful at all or just a little successful.